# Docker + NGINX + Nodejs + Sveltekit + PM2 GET ERROR net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, svelte, pm2

Hello I'm having a hard time solving this problem, getting ERROR `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) when trying to deploy on the production server.`

The simple login page is not loading, but when I use the command `curl` to get the page it displays perfectly fine in the terminal.

I'm using Docker + Docker compose + NGINX + Nodejs + SvelteKit + PM2, for the configuration of the server ("Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)").

I had set up a test repo to make it work and then use that configuration for the real project, and it worked, but I don't know why it's not working in the real one. [This is the test repo](https://github.com/Naty-S/svelte-prisma-nginx-docker)

I have searched and tried all the solutions I encountered.

1. Adding in the `default.conf` file for the webpage, in the `location /` directive

- `proxy_read_timeout 120s;`
- `proxy_buffering off;`
- 

```
proxy_buffers 8 1024k;
proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
```

- 

```
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

- 

```
proxy_no_cache 1;
# even if cached, don't try to use it
proxy_cache_bypass 1;
```

- 

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

- 

```
proxy_buffers 16 4k;
proxy_buffer_size 2k;
```

- `proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;`
- `proxy_set_header Content-Encoding identity;`
- `fastcgi_read_timeout 300;`
- `proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;`

2. checking the owner:group of the `/var/chache/nginx` and `etc/nginx` folders in the container (`/var/lib/nginx` folder does not exist)

- `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml exec nginx ls -l var/cache`
  [image: result]
- `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml exec nginx ls -l var/cache/nginx` (here the user was originally `nginx`
  [image: result]
- `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml exec nginx ls -l etc/nginx`
  [image: result]

3. Changed the user for `nginx.conf` file to `user root;`, it uses `user nginx;` by default. I'm using root because I need to do all the configurations in the root user in the server.
4. Uncommented `gzip on` in the `nginx.conf` file
5. Checked the memory usage for the containers, some said that its because nginx can't write in the cache for large responses

- size of response for login page: `curl -so /dev/null <login-url> -w '%{size_download}'` -> 24646 bytes = 0.023504257202148438 MB
- `df -h` in the server
  [image: df -h]
- `docker stats`
  [image: result]

6. Increasing the size for memory limit in the nginx container: `mem_limit: 10240M" (10Gb)

I haven't tried changing the cache directory of nginx for the context `proxy_temp_path`, because I'm not sure where to point it.

- default.conf file

```
# http
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  #
  server_name ${SERVER_NAME};

  #
  root ${NGINX_ROOT};

  location / {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

#    proxy_no_cache 1;
    # even if cached, don't try to use it
 #   proxy_cache_bypass 1;


    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;

    proxy_set_header Content-Encoding identity;

    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;

#    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_read_timeout 300s;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;


    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    # Redirects from port 80 to 3000
    # (where app is listening, the one served by with pm2)
    proxy_pass ${NGINX_PROXY_PASS};
  }
}
```

- nginx.conf file

```
user  root;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

- Dockerfile

```
## Pull the Node.js Docker base image from https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:18-slim AS build


ARG SERVER_NAME


## Set the Node environment to development to ensure all packages are installed
ENV NODE_ENV development


## Change our current working directory, where app its developed
WORKDIR /var/www/${SERVER_NAME}


## Copy over `package.json` and lock files to optimize the build process
COPY package*.json ./


## Install dependencies
RUN npm i pm2 -g
RUN npm i
RUN npm fund

# Copy all local files into the image.
COPY . .


## Generate prisma client
RUN npx prisma generate


## Set the Node environment to production
ENV NODE_ENV production


## build app
RUN npm run build && npm prune --omit=dev


## Expose port 3000 so it's accessible from outside of the Docker container
EXPOSE 3000


## Start app already built
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "build/index.js"]
```

- docker-compose.yml file

```
## see https://docs.docker.com/compose/
version: '3.9'

services:
  sinai:
    container_name: sinai
    image: sinai
    restart: on-failure:3
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
        delay: 5s
        window: 120s
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
      args:
        - SERVER_NAME=${SERVER_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      # Ensure hot-module reload works, don't have to restart our container to see changes.
      - ./:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}
      # To avoid copying over local Node modules to Docker
      - docker_node_modules:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}/node_modules
      # share build and static files with nginx
      - app_build:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}/build
      - app_static:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}/static


  ## Execute and run the Postgres database container on port 5432.
  # Access the database, set the environment
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14
    hostname: postgres
    restart: on-failure:3
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
        delay: 5s
        window: 120s
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${PG_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB}
      PGDATA: ${PG_DATA}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:${PG_DATA}
      - ./prisma/db/sinai.gz:/var/lib/postgresql/sinai.gz


  ##
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    restart: on-failure:3
    command: [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
    mem_limit: "10240M"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
        delay: 5s
        window: 120s
    env_file:
      - .env
    links:
      - sinai
    depends_on:
      - sinai
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_HTTP_PORT}:80
    environment: # las usa el .conf
      - SERVER_NAME=${SERVER_NAME}
      - NGINX_ROOT=${NGINX_ROOT}
      - NGINX_PROXY_PASS=${NGINX_PROXY_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/prod/default.conf.template:/etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
      - ./nginx/prod/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - app_build:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}/build
      - app_static:/var/www/${SERVER_NAME}/static


volumes:
  pgdata:
  docker_node_modules:
  app_build:
  app_static:
```

- package.json

```
{
...
        "devDependencies": {
                "@playwright/test": "^1.22.2",
                "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0-next.86",
                "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.405",
                "eslint": "^8.16.0",
                "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
                "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
                "prettier": "^2.6.2",
                "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
                "prisma": "^4.0.0",
                "svelte": "^3.44.0",
                "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
                "typescript": "^4.7.4",
                "vite": "^3.2.5"
        },
        "type": "module",
        "dependencies": {
                "@prisma/client": "^4.0.0",
                "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
                "cookie": "^0.5.0",
                "cs-list": "^1.0.5",
                "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
                "print-js": "^1.6.0",
                "svelte-forms-lib": "^2.0.1",
                "yup": "^0.32.11"
        }
}
```

I'm not using the latest version neither the stable version 1 for SvelteKit because I started the project before the release and there are a lot of changes to do, and I don't have the time to solve the problem that will arise from that. So, I just updated to the version just before the big change.

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks a lot!!

**UPDATE**
Ok, I figure out what was the problem after thinking that nginx wasn't the problem, it was because a route in te "manifest.json" wasn't with the correct syntax ಠ_ಠ ¯_(ツ)_/¯ I was using $lib, after using the full route it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure out what was the problem after thinking that nginx wasn't the problem, it was because a route in te "manifest.json" wasn't with the correct syntax ಠ_ಠ ¯_(ツ)_/¯ I was using $lib, after using the full route it worked just fine